# git push origin master -> DENIED by fallthru

Tags: git, gitolite

When I try to 'git push origin master' I get the error 'DENIED by fallthru'

I've spent the last three hours googling. I can't figure out how to fix it.

gitolite.log

```
2012-10-15.16:43:47 16930   ssh ARGV=david_neudorfer_lbox_com_1350337154    SOC=git-receive-pack 'Treasure-Hunt.git'    FROM=10.0.4.185
2012-10-15.16:43:47 16930       repo 'Treasure-Hunt' missing
2012-10-15.16:43:47 16930       access(Treasure-Hunt, david_neudorfer_lbox_com_1350337154, W, 'any'),-> W any Treasure-Hunt david_neudorfer_lbox_com_1350337154 DENIED by fallthru
2012-10-15.16:43:47 16930       trigger,Writable,access_1,ACCESS_1,Treasure-Hunt,david_neudorfer_lbox_com_1350337154,W,any,W any Treasure-Hunt david_neudorfer_lbox_com_1350337154 DENIED by fallthru
2012-10-15.16:43:47 16930   die W any Treasure-Hunt david_neudorfer_lbox_com_1350337154 DENIED by fallthru<<newline>>(or you mis-spelled the reponame)
```

gitolite.conf

```
repo    test_project
  RW+                            = david_neudorfer_lbox_com_1350344583
repo    projectsmadesimple-web
  RW+                            = david_neudorfer_lbox_com_1350344583
repo    treasure-hunt
  RW+                            = david_neudorfer_lbox_com_1350344583
```

I noticed that the numbers after the names are different. Hoping that had something to do with it I tried:

```
repo    test_project
  RW+                            = david_neudorfer_lbox_com_1350344583
  RW+                            = david_neudorfer_lbox_com_1350337154
```

Didn't work. Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: Have you checked whether the capitalization differences matter?

Comment: in the project name? I don't think thats it because this is happening on multiple projects.

Comment: For the repo name you have `treasure-hunt` in your config and `Treasure-Hunt` as the name of the repo you're trying to push. Have you tested at least one project where capitalization is a perfect match?

Comment: Took me a minute to find the gitolite install and a key I had authorized on it, but I've confirmed here that capitalization must be an exact match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [cjc343](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1038369/cjc343) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905870/git-push-origin-master-denied-by-fallthru/12908065#comment17483103_12905870), the last error line is telling:

```
2012-10-15.16:43:47 16930   die W any Treasure-Hunt 
                            DENIED by fallthru
                            (or you mis-spelled the reponame)
```

That error message comes from the [main() function of src/gitolite-shell](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/src/gitolite-shell#L114-L122), after calling the [src/lib/Gitolite/Conf/Load.pm repo_missing() function](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/src/lib/Gitolite/Conf/Load.pm#L187-L192).

```
sub repo_missing {
    my $repo = shift;
    sanity($repo);

    return not -d "$rc{GL_REPO_BASE}/$repo.git";
}
```

It looks for a directory, which is, on Unix system, case sensitive.

Then you need to fix the id issue: you should be authenticated always with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

Solved:
In my case I moved repo from my account to a group so path to the repo changed on remote but not in my local repo.

So I changed path in local repo (config file):

```
[remote "origin"]
url = git@git.me:mygroup/repo.git              // previously git@git.me:myname/repo.git
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```